# Need Help in Converting Code from JS to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Here is the Js Code:

```
n = o.length,
i = "";
for (e = 0; n > e; ++e) e % 3 === 0 && (i += o.substring(e, e + 1));
```

and C# Code is

```
int  n = newTemp.Length;
string final = "";
for (int e = 0; n > e; ++e)
{
     if( e%3==0 )
       {
          final += newTemp.Substring(e, e + 1);
       }
}
```

but code of C# not giving the same result as JS does.

Comment: How are the results different?

Comment: @rory.ap code is okay ?

Comment: I don't know.  It would help if I knew how the "results" are different.

Comment: what is `o` in js and `newTemp` in C# ??

Answer (score 1):

c# substring is different than js substring.

in js:

```
text.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

[more details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

in C#:

```
text.Substring(startIndex, subtextLength);
```

[More Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your C# version is that JS substring takes a *start index* and an *end index*, where in C# substring takes a *start index* and a ***substring length***.

Also, for what your code is doing (only taking a single character), it might be better to do something like this:

```
int length = inputString.Length;
string result= "";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (i%3 == 0) result += inputString[i];
}
```

(The changes to variable names and the for loop are just to make things more readable).